# AudioContext.currentTime sometimes freezes for ~230ms shortly after start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm creating a music related app using Web Audio API, which requires precisely synchronizing sound, visuals and MIDI input processing.

The sound production follows the pattern described [in this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/): `requestAnimationFrame` regularly calls a function that schedules events on the `AudioContext`. This works fine most of the time, except in some occasions where the audio inexplicably lags behind the visuals.

After much poking around, I ran into the [AudioContext.currentTime specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#BaseAudioContext-attributes) which hints:

> Elapsed time in this system corresponds to elapsed time in the audio stream generated by the BaseAudioContext, which may not be synchronized with other clocks in the system.

And indeed I was able to verify that these sporadic delays in the audio come down to a problem in the AudioContext clock itself, which seems to pause for a bit *sometimes* just after starting up. Note that this doesn't happen every time, but frequently enough to be an issue (maybe 10-15% of the time...). Each time it happens the pattern is the same: `currentTime` starts increasing then gets stuck at 23ms for a bit, then starts going again regularly without any further issue after accumulating a total of ~230ms of lag behind the system/wall clock...

I've created a simple script which reproduces the problem (if you want to try it, just open the console to see the output, and press any key to start the test... as the issue is sporadic you may need to retry or sometimes reload multiple times before it happens...):

```
<script>

const audioContext = new AudioContext();

// reference points for both clocks (JS and audioContext)
var animStartTime = null;
var audioStartTime = null;

// loop function to be called by requestAnimationFrame
function play(timestamp) {
    // set animStartTime on first invocation
    if (animStartTime == null) animStartTime = timestamp;

    // compute elapsed time for both clocks
    var animElapsedTime = timestamp - animStartTime;
    var audioElapsedTime = (audioContext.currentTime - audioStartTime) * 1000;

    console.log('Animation ts: ' + animElapsedTime +
        ', Audio ts: ' + audioElapsedTime +
        ', Diff: ' + (animElapsedTime - audioElapsedTime)
    );

    // keep this going for 1 second
    if (animElapsedTime < 1000)
        requestAnimationFrame(play);
}

function start() {
    audioStartTime = audioContext.currentTime;
    animStartTime = null;  // use the timestamp provided by requestAnimationFrame

    // create a simple oscillator and schedule it to produce a single beep when it starts
    const osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
    osc.frequency.value = 800;
    osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
    osc.start(audioStartTime);
    osc.stop(audioStartTime + 0.03);

    // launch animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(play);
}

// press any key to start the test
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {start()});

</script>
```

And here is the console output of a bogus run, where you can see the Audio timestamp freezing up to a delay of ~230ms behind the JS main thread timestamp before starting again:
[image: console output showing a log on audioContext.currentTime]

Could someone explain to me:

1. What is going on? Why is this freezing sporadically?
2. Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I can think of some ways to mitigate the issue if I can get convinced that it happens only when starting up, but without fully understanding the root cause I fear seeing these freezes happen again at other times...

Comment: Is this consistent across all major browsers?

Comment: Good question, my app also relies on WebMIDI which is not available on Firefox and Safari so I've only validated this on Chrome so far. But I did verify it in Chrome on both a Macbook Pro running MacOS and a desktop running Ubuntu (only the timings differ, the total lag is lower on the OSX machine at 100-130ms).

Comment: Bare in mind that WebAudio is non standard across browsers. You are in experimental territory so expect some bumps along the way. If your application relies on WebMIDI I think it might be worthwhile getting in touch with maintainer directly https://studiocode.dev/about/

Answer (score 1):

This is probably https://crbug.com/693978 Resuming the context may take "some" time.

Unfortunately, they don't really wait for the context has started before resolving the Promise returned by `context.resume()`, so we have to resort to ugly workarounds.
One such workaround would be to wait for `currentTime` to start updating after `context.resume()` resolves before starting your animation.

```js
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

// reference points for both clocks (JS and audioContext)
var animStartTime = null;
var audioStartTime = null;

// loop function to be called by requestAnimationFrame
function play(timestamp) {
  // set animStartTime on first invocation
  if (animStartTime == null) animStartTime = timestamp;

  // compute elapsed time for both clocks
  var animElapsedTime = timestamp - animStartTime;
  var audioElapsedTime = (audioContext.currentTime - audioStartTime) * 1000;

  console.log('Animation ts: ' + animElapsedTime +
    ', Audio ts: ' + audioElapsedTime +
    ', Diff: ' + (animElapsedTime - audioElapsedTime)
  );

  // keep this going for 1 second
  if (animElapsedTime < 1000)
    requestAnimationFrame(play);
}

async function start() {
  // wait for the context to resume
  // needs to be there, for we still handle the user-gesture
  await audioContext.resume();
  // though resume() might be a lie in Chrome,
  // so we also wait for currentTime to update
  const startTime = audioContext.currentTime;
  while (startTime === audioContext.currentTime) {
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res));
  }
  // now our AudioContext is ready.

  audioStartTime = audioContext.currentTime;
  animStartTime = null; // use the timestamp provided by requestAnimationFrame

  // create a simple oscillator and schedule it to produce a single beep when it starts
  const osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = 800;
  osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
  osc.start(0);
  osc.stop(0.3);

  // launch animation loop
  requestAnimationFrame(play);
}

// using a button for a clearer snippet
document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener('click', start);
```

```html
<button>start</button>
```

Comment: Interesting, the symptoms do look similar, but in my case I'm not using suspend / resume which seems to be the source of the issue in that ticket... also they don't mention the randomness I'm experiencing, and looks like they closed that issue a few years ago... so I'm not convinced that this is the same thing!

Comment: Your context **starts** suspended on Chrome, until you interact with the page. And they never fixed that issue, they just deemed it's acceptable. The randomness would come from the fact it's linked to the output device, waking this device up takes time, random time (it may already be active and not require any time at all). And anyway, doesn't the workaround work for you?